# Pass Object to Class via Constructor

Tags: c++

Why does this code not work:

```
int main () {

Bob bob;
bob.giveANewFredSomeData();
Fred::sharedFred.getANumber(); //Crashes here due to someData inside fred being NULL

return 0;
}

Class Data {
    int aNumber;
}

Class Bob {
   void giveANewFredSomeData{
     Data data;

     Fred::sharedFred = new Fred(data);

   }
}

Class Fred {
  Data someData;

  static sharedFred;

  Fred (Data data) {
    someData = data;
  }

  int getANumber(){
   return someData.aNumber 
 }
}
```

Comment: Be an angel and wack the code in the post...

Comment: How about some **code**?

Comment: Please show in pseudocode or actual code what you want to do. (You'll probably have to use manual memory management with new/delete and pass pointers around.)

Comment: Too many words. Don't circumlocute so much, just present some code.

Comment: +1 for posh word: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumlocution

Comment: OK, seems like a lot of people want code. Let's just ask to make sure: Anyone who does *not* want to see some code?

Comment: @DanielFrey: Can I vote to *not* want to see `ordinary words` dressed up as `though` they were code?

Comment: Nobody has yet commented on the miraculous "a member variable is null" yet...

Comment: I'm still reading up on Circumlocution

Comment: @KerrekSB That's because everyone is busy congratulating everyone else on their super-witty remarks.

Comment: @KerrekSB If you're referring to my answer, feel free to improve it. However I don't feel that a question in this form deserves anything more :)

Comment: @BartoszKP: Fair enough, you're off the hook. This time. I'll be watching you :-)

Comment: No circumlocution at all in that comment, @Kerrek SB

Comment: OP: Instead of saying, "I have a method, method is called "jim", and it lives in a class which I call "class Klaus", and after I call it, a variable is null". you should say concisely: "Please consider this code: `struct Klaus { void jim() { x = NULL; } void * x; };` Why is `x` null after I call `jim()`? In my opinion it should be XYZ because of ABC. Could you please explain my mistake?" That way we have something definite to work on, and we know what you were thinking and can hopefully help you stop where you went wrong.

Comment: What is the definition of `User`? It looks like the `User` constructor isn't doing what you expect. And what is the default value of `root`?

Comment: @JamesCampbell good that you've cleared up the irrelevant part in the last method, however please provide the missing relevant parts - where is `currentUser` and `User`?

Comment: Wait: is `currentUser->data` actually different from `root`? Or are both null, because that's just the default value for a `JSon::Value`?

Comment: How do you verify that it's null after the method?

Comment: No problem :) User is just a subclass of object. root at the point I pass it to the constructor is actually full of JSON data which has been passed from a HTTP Response, I use this library http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/ . root is a JSON::Value from that library.

Comment: This is too labyrinthine to disentangle. If you can make a self-contained, small example, that would help a lot. As it stands, it seems that all the problems occur in code that we *don't* see.

Comment: When I access  *currentUser* after it has been set and call *sessionToken*. My app crashes, when I navigate the backtrace in my IDE, it indicates that *currentUser* 's *data* is null

Comment: okay give me a second

Comment: Well, if you have a backtrace, step up the stack and check that all the values are what you expect along the way...

Comment: From this what can be seen here, the only possibility is that `logOut` has been called :)

Comment: User.cpp as it stands is silly - that's just self-assignment in the constructor?!

Comment: Ive modified it, should explain what i am doing, sorry if the syntax isn't correct. but it should be easier to understand.

Comment: Is self assignment a bad thing ? I've used alot of programming languages where you pass in variables visa the constructor and the class self assigns. Is this different in c++ (sorry im new to this language )

Comment: Just worked it out, I was setting the variable to itself rather than the parameter. Man its been a long day ..... stupid noob errorr, should of spotted that. sorry for wasting your time. But thanks for the help :)

Comment: nope still crashes :/

Comment: From this version, the only possibility I see is something wrong with the copy constructors of `Data`.

Comment: Looked into it, seems my JSON parser isn't storing the value of the JSON properly so its returning null :) thanks for your help :)

Comment: Good luck :) Do take a break, 5 minute walk usually boosts programming skills ;)

Comment: I can't help feeling like there should be a type somewhere in `static sharedFred;`, and that before you do `Fred::sharedFred = new Fred(data);`, it might be a good idea to initialize `data` to some actual, you know, value or something, before you try to read from it with `Fred::sharedFred.getANumber();`.

Comment: :) thanks for your help, turns out the json being given to my app was wrong. I put in sanity checks and fixed the issue with the API sending me the wrong JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not working because:

- You need a semicolon after the declaration of a class
- `static` is not a valid type
- `static` objects have to be initialized outside of their definition in the class in order to be used elsewhere in the code. You need something like: `Fred Fred::sharedFred;` before main
- Declaration of a function must have `()` in front of the function name before the `{}` braces
- the classes have to be in the scope of `main` function for them to be used, and also in the scope of each other depending on what is calling what. i.e. main has to be declared after the class and same for each class that calls another
- Properties/methods declared in a [class](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_classes_objects.htm) are private by default. To make group of properties/methods public, have the keyword `public` followed by a colon at the top of the group

Comment: +1 just for having the patience to write an actual answer when the posted code is clearly not even close to his actual code.